# Linespacing only for main text body

Tags: beamer, line-spacing

In a LaTeX beamer document, is there a way to change line spacing only for the main text body - i.e. for everything between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`? In particular if using `\linespread` and its variants in the preamble the line spacing will also increase in multi-line titles or if the respective beamertheme uses newlines in its layout.
I also tried using `\linespread` within a frame but to no avail.

Comment: Not terribly sure about Beamer, but check out the [setspace](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/setspace.html) package.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a title on each `frame`, your generic structure would probably resemble

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{<title>}
  % <frame content>
\end{frame}
```

As such, you have the `\frametitle` command as a hook that you can use to initiate a different line spacing for the remainder of the `frame`. And, instead of using the traditional `\linespread{<factor>}` to modify the spacing, use `\setstretch{<factor>}` from the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace). To that end, include the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\let\oldframetitle\frametitle% Store \frametitle in \oldframetitle
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{%
  \oldframetitle{#1}\setstretch{2}}
```

This will typeset the regular `\frametitle` and immediately after it call `\setstretch{2}` which increases ("doubles") the line spacing for the remainder of the group. Since the `frame` environment provides the necessary scope boundary, `\setstretch` only has an effect until `\end{frame}`. This allows for only the `frame` content to be typeset under a different line spacing, leaving titles untouched in terms of this stretch factor. Additionally, a natural form of automation by redefinition of the existing commands allow for legible and transferable code.

Here's a minimal example showing this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\let\oldframetitle\frametitle% Store old \frametitle in \oldframetitle
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{% Redefine \frametitle
  \oldframetitle{#1}\setstretch{2}}
%\setstretch{2} <--- uncomment to see the global effect of \setstretch{2}
\title{Random title}
\subtitle{Random subtitle}
\author{Random Randofsky}
\institute{Random institute, Random City 1000, Randomia}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Random section 1}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This frame title is extremely long and spans at least two lines}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Random stuff Random stuff
    \item \itshape{more random stuff}
    \item Random stuff...
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Random section 2}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Here is another long frame title - this time it spans more than 
    just two lines of the frame; it actually spans three lines}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\section{Random section 3}
\begin{frame}
  This frame has no title. So, the contents is not affected by line spacing changes
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Random stuff Random stuff
    \item \itshape{more random stuff}
    \item Random stuff...
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section{Random section 4}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{About this frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Random stuff Random stuff
    \item \itshape{more random stuff}
    \item Random stuff...
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this relies on the fact that your `frame` has the structure suggested at the start. So, a `frame` *without* a title would be void of any line spacing alterations. Since you didn't mention this in your question, I assume this is not a problem. However, such modifications are always possible, given an alternative/suitable hook.

The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was merely used to provide filler text on slide 4.

<sup>To see the global effect of `\setspace{2}` on the `frame` titles, uncomment `\setspace{2}` in the preamble.</sup>